# Why Today Notification Widget crashes at startup?

Tags: ios, ios8-today-widget

Today Notification Widget launch crashes with the following error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** setObjectForKey: object
>   cannot be nil (key: <__NSConcreteUUID 0x170026460>
>   C492718F-C23C-4FC8-AE0F-ED5CE3141xxx)'

`ViewDidLoad` not even gets called

Any idea why?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Today Extension Crashes before launching on iOS 8.1.2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28153273/today-extension-crashes-before-launching-on-ios-8-1-2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if `NotificationCenter.framework` is included into your project's current selected target or if there is any other framework missing.

Comment: would it even compile if it were missing?

Comment: @Daij-Djan It seemed it was missing inside notification target, after I added it won't crash at run

Comment: @Daij-Djan  Tried to add google analytics and admob and it's frameworks and it was selected target from TodayNotificationWidget and after I removed them because I had compile problems I might removed that framework by mistake and after adding it, it didn't crash after launch...

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're trying to write a nil value into a dictionary or NSUserDefaults. Your controller will be initialized before `viewDidLoad` is called. Did you override the initializer?

I think you need to provide more information. Maybe post your controller code?